# yml configuration file with spring framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, jhipster

I'm working on jhipster project with spring framework that have yml configuration file ,I need to get url and serverport parameters from application.yml file that found in resource/config path,I have the following code but it print null.

configuration.yml file

```
server:
     port: 8081

spring:
    devtools:
       restart:
         enabled: true
    datasource:
       url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/adap_ms
```

java class

```
  @Configuration
  public class Configuration {

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String url;

  @Value("${server.port}")
  private String serverPort;

  public void generateReport() throws Exception{ 
     System.out.println(url);
     System.out.println(serverPort);
 }
```

Comment: Try renaming the file as `resources/config/application.yml`

Answer (score 2):

I think your resource directory should be resource**s**/config. Spring boot consider files under config directory in the class path as well as current directory from which you run your application as configuration files. Check the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) in section 24.3.

Edited based on Joost's comment. Yeah, you may have to change the configuration.yml file name to application.yml